# Meaning of "f.a." in the species name

Tags: nomenclature, yeast

What does "f.a." stand for in the name of the "Wickerhamomyces menglaensis f.a." yeast species mentioned in this article https://ijs.microbiologyresearch.org/content/journal/ijsem/10.1099/ijsem.0.003350 ?

Comment: The link to the journal seems to be broken. Can you check the doi and include it instead?

Comment: it's also nice if you include a complete citation :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Forma asexualis" as explained in [another paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Andrey_Yurkov/publication/267815193_Two_yeast_species_Cystobasidium_psychroaquaticum_fa_sp_nov_and_Cystobasidium_rietchieii_fa_sp_nov_isolated_from_natural_environments_and_the_transfer_of_Rhodotorula_minuta_clade_members_to_the_genus_C/links/54aa61810cf274dc0b5c167d/Two-yeast-species-Cystobasidium-psychroaquaticum-fa-sp-nov-and-Cystobasidium-rietchieii-fa-sp-nov-isolated-from-natural-environments-and-the-transfer-of-Rhodotorula-minuta-clade-members-to-the-genus.pdf)

> The authors favor the use of the expression forma asexualis (f.a.) in the
>   description of anamorphic species of the genus
>   Cystobasidium and this decision follows the current
>   practice of reclassification of asexual yeast taxa (see
>   e.g. Lachance 2012; Groenewald and Smith 2013;
>   Daniel et al. 2013; Selbmann et al. 2014)
>
> - Lachance MA (2012) [In defense of yeast sexual life cycles: the
>     forma asexualis](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Marc-Andre_Lachance/publication/280623445_In_defense_of_yeast_sexual_life_cycles_The_forma_asexualis-an_informal_proposal/links/55ddb03b08aeaa26af0ec9c2/In-defense-of-yeast-sexual-life-cycles-The-forma-asexualis-an-informal-proposal.pdf): an informal proposal. Yeast Newslett
>     61:24–25

Comment: Nice answer. So does `f.a` mean the asexual strains of the same species?

Comment: @WYSIWYG: yes. Before this change, the anamorph and teleomorph had to have different names, and were even in different genera... because they had different appearance.

Comment: @WYSIWYG: actually the rules are more complicated for the existing names https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleomorph,_anamorph_and_holomorph#One_fungus,_one_name i.e. they didn't force them out; that's why you mostly see "f.a." in combination with sp.nov (or more rarely comb.nov.) on a search.

Comment: So what do `sp. nov.` and `comb.nov.` mean? Could you also add your comments to the answer as it would be useful to others?